# Application insights metrics and custom data strange behavior

Tags: azure-application-insights

I noticed strange behavior of users metric in app insights. On azure portal I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZy29.jpg) statistics.

How does it possible to have event without user? I'm using application insights via [angular-applicationinsights](https://github.com/khaines/angular-applicationinsights) module.

Also sometimes it loses my custom data fields.

Does anybody have the same issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This SDK is not officially supported as it's not from Microsoft organization on GitHub. However if this SDK sends `userId` field with events - UI should correctly calculate user/session settings.

Can you please validate that this SDK in fact sends `userId` filed with the events.